# Why does my 'if' code with != '' return true when I input 0, which is supposed to be a falsey value?

Tags: python, if-statement

newbie learning python here. Doing a course online and ran into some trouble here:

Why does my 'if' code with != '' return true when I input 0, which is supposed to be a falsey value?

Here is the code

```
print('Enter a name')
name = input()
if name != '':
    print('Thank you for entering a name, ' + name)
else:
    print('You didn\'t enter a name')
```

The output is:

```
Enter a name
0
Thank you for entering a name, 0
```

How would this be false?

Comment: _0, which is supposed to be a falsey value_ You aren't testing the general truthiness of `name`; you're testing whether it is a blank string.  To put it another way, `False` isn't equal to `''` either.

Comment: Whether something is falsey is only pertinent if you're casting it to a boolean. No such cast happens here. `bool(int(input))` would become `False` with `input='0'`, as would `bool('')`.

Comment: What are valid names?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have `0`, you have `'0'`, a string of length 1. Any non-empty string is considered true:

```
>>> name = input()
0
>>> name
'0'
>>> len(name)
1
>>> type(name)
<class 'str'>
>>> bool(name)  # truth value
True
```

Because it is a string with a single character in it, it is also not equal to `''`, the empty string and your `if name != '':` test passes.

You have a string because in Python 3, `input()` always returns strings.

If you had an `int` object with the value `0`, then yes, it would be false-y:

```
>>> falsey = 0
>>> type(falsey)
<class 'int'>
>>> bool(falsey)
False
```

You'd have to convert your string to an integer:

```
>>> int(name)
0
>>> type(int(name))
<class 'int'>
>>> bool(int(name))
False
```

However, converting to an integer doesn't make much sense when you are asking for someone's *name*. A name is *text*, not a number.

So, unless you have a clear, specific reason to further validate what the user entered to check that the value is an actual name, there is no point in testing for the number `0` here. Just stick to what you have, perhaps by just using:

```
if name:
    # ... name is not empty
```

Comment: This is all true, but even if they had `0`, it wouldn't be equal to `''`.

Comment: what happens if I input: int(0) instead of 0?

Comment: Yes, which is why their actual code outputs *Thank you..., 0`

Comment: How do I make it return false?

Comment: @LseLibrary: Please be clearer in what you expect to happen. You could just test for `name != '0'` but that’s not a very sensible test, for example.

Comment: So you are saying there isn't a way to make it return false, the way the code is now?

Comment: @LseLibrary: Put differently: why do you need to test for `'0'`?

Comment: @LseLibrary: `name != '0'` would return false when you enter `0`. But again, that's not a very good test if all you want to know if the user has entered a name. And who's to say that `'0'` is not a name?

Answer (score 0):

the input() function takes in your 0 as a name, and than your name is '0',
and not ''. a more common way of doing this, would be:

```
if len(name) > 0:
    print('Thank you for entering a name, ' + name)
else:
    print('You didn\'t enter a name')
```

Comment: or just `if name:`

Comment: Backticks are meant for code segments of less than a line. Four-space indents should be used for full-line or multi-line code blocks -- see my edit. That way you get syntax highlighting, and the colored background extends all the way to the right edge.

Comment: @LseLibrary: `if name:`, `if name != '':` and `if len(name) > 0:` *all test the same thing*, if `name` is a always a string. But `if name:` is the Pythonic form there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import re

name = input()
if re.match('[a-zA-Z]+', name):  # returns None if not match, a match object otherwise.
    print("Thank you for entering your name, {}.".format(name))
else:
    print("Oops! You didn't entered a valid name.")
```